# How to remove lines in DrawGrid?

Tags: delphi, canvas

I have a DrawGrid with FixedCols = 0, FixedRows = 0 and GridLineWidth = 0, GoRowSelect = True and this OnPaint:

```
procedure TForm1.DrawGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
var Canvas: TCanvas;
begin
  Canvas := DrawGrid1.Canvas;

  Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
  Canvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
  Canvas.Pen.Style := psSolid;
  Canvas.Pen.Mode := pmCopy;

  Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
end;
```

Yet when I run the program and select the rows I see some lines that should not be there.

How can I remove default lines?

[image: Example]

Comment: Set DefaultDrawing to false.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Thanks, should do the trick!

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, I can duplicate the problem without any drawing handler attached at all. It seems the control has got some drawing glitches when row select is enabled.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I did DefaultDrawing = false and it's now all good. Seems my drawing was breaking default drawing hence the glitches. Anyway you might want to post your comment as the answer. If you so I'll accept it. Thanks!